# Why doesn't Spotlight look inside shell scripts?

Tags: macos, terminal, spotlight

I have a bunch of shell scripts (all plain text files) in `/usr/local/scripts`

If I do `fgrep -il '@todo' *` there are 14 files which match.

If I do `mdfind -onlyin /usr/local/scripts '@TODO'` there are no results.

How do I get Spotlight to search these files?

---

n.b. Previous answers suggest adding filetypes to

`/System/Library/Spotlight/RichText.mdimporter/Contents/Info.plist`

but that file can no longer be edited. I'm not even sure what I would add to that file if I *could* edit it.

Comment: My hunch is that the directory is excluded outright. You can probably confirm that changing the file type to text or another one you know would and is indexed when it’s on your desktop. May be a while to unearth if inclusions are even possible now.

Comment: Huh. You might be right. I know how to _exclude_ directories from Spotlight, but I don't know how to _add_ one.

Comment: tbh I don't use Spotlight much, partly because of this kind of failing - as far as I'm aware it doesn't look in System Folders at all. I always use [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware) to look for anything 'difficult'. It's not indexed so it's slower, but it's sure to find it if it's there.

Comment: You can try `mdimport -i -d1 /usr/local/scripts` to trigger the search. Don't know whether it works for directories Spotlight excludes by default.